# Too many positional arguments along with Center() and GridVew()?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.
When I trying to build an app, an error showing as

```
[{  
    "resource": "/d:/Learn Fluter    
 Self/Flutter_Projects/Demo_App/flutter_application_1/lib/home.dart",   
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",  
    "code": {  
        "value": "extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named",  
        "target": {  
            "$mid": 1,  
            "path": "/diagnostics/extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named",  
            "scheme": "https",  
            "authority": "dart.dev"  
        }    
    },    
    "severity": 8,  
    "message": **"Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.\nTry removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."**,  
    "source": "dart",  
    "startLineNumber": 25,  
    "startColumn": 7,  
    "endLineNumber": 38,  
    "endColumn": 8  
}]
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body:
          // Column(
          //   children: [
          Center(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Text(
              'CarVariants',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ),
      GridView.count(
        // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
        // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
        children: List.generate(100, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Item $index',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
      // Container(
      //   child: Image.asset('assets/images/sedan.png'),
      // ),
      // Container(
      //   child: Image.asset('assets/images/suv.png'),
      // ),
      //   ],
      // ),
    );
  }

  AppBar appBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'CarBay',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 79, 218, 125),
      elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/icons/backButton.svg',
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Scaffold and body. The body parameter only takes one child, and your body has a Center and a GridView widget. I see you have commented out your Column, but in your setup you will need the Column since it can take multiple children. That way the body will have one child, the Column. Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Text(
                'CarVariants',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
              // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
              children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar appBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'CarBay',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 79, 218, 125),
      elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/icons/backButton.svg',
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable reply.
Please suggest me some flutter development references from basics.

Answer (score 0):

why are you commenting body:Column and its Children[]??
also make sure to wrap GridView.count with a SizedBox and give sizedBox a height

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      const Center(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Text(
              'CarVariants',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 400,
        child: GridView.count(
          // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
          // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
          children: List.generate(item.length, (index) {
            return Text(
              'Item ${item[index]}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ]));
```

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable reply.
Please suggest me some flutter development references from basics.

Comment: Use https://youtu.be/CzRQ9mnmh44?si=tglw3W6lsSBXZXGH   to watch full flutter and dart course and also be sure to give score to my answer if it helped you.